# Django Doubling the path leading to a 404

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to redirect the user to another page if login is successful and leading the user to the login page if the login is unsuccessful. However, Django is leading me to the path 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginuser/loginuser` 
in either case.

Can someone point out the mistake and offer a correction?

**views.py**

```
def loginuser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return render(request,'getstarted.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request,"Invalid Credentials!")
            return render(request,'login.html')

    else:
        return render(request,"login.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path("",views.HomePage,name="home"),
path("registeruser.html/",views.RegisterUser,name='registeruser'),
path("registerdoctor.html/",views.RegisterDoctor,name='registerdoctor'),
path("loginuser/",views.loginuser,name='login'),
path("logoutuser/",views.logoutuser,name='logout'),
path('aboutus/',views.about,name='about'),
path('feedback/',views.feedback,name='feedback'),
path('start/',views.getstarted,name='getstarted'),
]
```

**login.html**

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form class="" action="loginuser" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Log In!">

  <div class="error">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <h3>{{message}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you provide some more details, as your question not getting cleared.

Comment: Did you set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`?

Comment: Hi. What I mean to say is instead of redirecting to getstarted.html when the login is successful and to login.html when the login is unsuccessful, I am always being lead to 'loginuser/loginuser' which is not a valid path/url.

Comment: I haven't set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

Comment: The problem is not coming from this code. You need to show your template. (However, note that you must always *redirect* after a successful POST, rather than rendering another template.)

Comment: Hi. I'm adding the template. Initially, I was redirecting but I tried rendering to get rid of this problem.